# Find $n^{23}$ with the least multiplication

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

$n$ is an arbitrary real number. By **only** using multiplication, you are asked to find $n^{23}$ with the least amount of multiplication operation.

**Note**: You can only use $n$ or the results you can with multiplications as examplified below.

For example if this question is asked for $n^4$, the answer would be $2$:

1.

> $n\times n=n^2$

2.

> $n^2\times n^2=n^4$

Comment: You could also make this an addition problem - how do you sum to 23 using only "1", "+", and the result of previous sums?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.

> $n \times n = n^2$

2.

> $n\times n^2 = n^3$

3.

> $n^3\times n^2=n^5$

4.

> $n^5\times n^5=n^{10}$

5.

> $n^{10}\times n^{10}=n^{20}$

6.

> $n^{20}\times n^{3}=n^{23}$

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling I was looking for this!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is

> 7 times.
>
> 1. $a^{2\phantom0} = a^\phantom{{00}} \times a$
>
>    $a^{3\phantom0} = a^{2\phantom0}   \times a$
>
>    $a^{5\phantom0} = a^{3\phantom0}   \times a^2$
>
>    $a^{6\phantom0} = a^{5\phantom0}   \times a$
>
>    $a^{11}         = a^{6\phantom0}   \times a^5$
>
>    $a^{22}         = a^{11}           \times a^{11}$
>
>    $a^{23}         = a^{22}           \times a$

as for $a^{22}$ it took 6 multiplications and for $a^{23}$ it is one more.